# Convergence in the $L^1\cap L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

So if $(f_n)_n\subset  L^1\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$,  $f_n\rightarrow f$ under $L^1$ norm and $f_n\rightarrow g$ under $L^2$ norm. Does it follow $f=g$  a.e and $f\in L^1\cap L^2$? More generally, if $(f_n)_n$ under a norm in $L^1\cap L^2$: ($|\cdot |=\max(|\cdot |_1, |\cdot |_2)$) converge to $f$, does it follow $f\in L^1\cap L^2$? I know that $L^1\cap L^2\subset L^r$ for any $1\leq r\leq 2$.

Any hints, ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If $f_n\to h$ in $L^p$ norm then $f_n\to h$ pointwise almost everywhere, at least along a subsequence. Passing to the subsequence (one will have to do it twice, one for each norm), $f_n\to f$ pointwise almost everywhere and $f_n\to g$ pointwise almost everywhere. Therefore $f$ and $g$ must agree almost everywhere.

Comment: Well, how do you know the two subsequences you are using are the same? We can deduce there exists subseq, $f_{n_k}$ and $f_{n_l}$ such that $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ and $f_{n_l}$ converges to $g$

Comment: Do something similar to diagonalization. $f_{n_k} \to g$ in $L^2$ since it's a subsequence of a $L^2$-convergent sequence. Extract a subsubsequence using this to get pointwise a.e. convergence to both functions.